# HTML5 toDataURL to Google Drive SDK - Multipart Upload with JPEG Data

Tags: html5-canvas

The multipart upload example [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#multipart) mentions JPEG data . What exactly is it ? How do I fetch it out of an HTML IMG element ? I tried sending the dataUri ( after creating a canvas with drawImage() and extracting its dataUri ; it did not work .

```
this.sendToDrive = function () {
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.createElement("img");
var that = this;
img.addEventListener("load", function () {
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);
//window.open(dataUrl);
var binaryData = dataUrl.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg);base64,/,  "");
that.transmitFile(dataUrl, that.title(), token);
});
img.setAttribute("src", this.src);
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
}
```

I do get the complete image in a new tab (window.open() ), but if I transmit it using the 'transmitFile()' method - which simply sends a multipart post to google drive and leads to a 200 ,and download the file created in the drive, it does not work. I leads to errors like Error interpreting JPEG image file (Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x2f 0x39)) . The data url is correct for sure, but is it what needs to be sent as the 'jpeg data' ? I get similar errors if I use window.btoa(dataUrl) or window.atob(dataUrl).

Comment: please review your question. It sounds like you need help with Javascript handling of DOM data. You haven't posted any code, or any error messages. As it stands, your questions will be closed.

Comment: Bu that is what the issue I am facing. canvas.toDataURL() does not work here -leads to an empty file in drive . I am trying to figure out what exactly is expected here - the JPEG data

Comment: @pinoyyid  nothing seems to be working - the dataUrl is correct for sure. If I run window.open(dataUrl)- I get the image . But if I send it to the drive , it does not work - I get some JPEG error - Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x2f 0x39

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I am facing a similar issue.